# Wrap/Indentation style for arithmetic expressions in Eclipse CDT

Tags: coding-style, eclipse-cdt

I'm using a customized Code style for Eclipse that suits my taste and needs. The problem is that, as far as I figured out, the setting I desire is not part of the code style dialogue presented to me by Eclipse (latest version, btw).

Here's what I want:

```
int lenghty_sum =  a_function_with_a_long_name(double some_argument) 
                 + another_lengthy_function();
```

That is, the operands should be aligned column-wise. What Eclipse produces, however, is something more like

```
int lengthy_sum = a_function_with_a_long_name(double some_argument)
  + another_lenghty_function();
```

which I find a bit messy to read.

Comment: My answer is incorrect, but I can't delete it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I take it back. Disregard this answer. It's incorrect. : /**

There's a trickiness to the formatter/code styler settings. You can determine properties on branches in addition to the more obvious thing of setting the leaf nodes of the settings tree.

So even though the `Expressions` branch only has `Conditionals`, and `Initializer list` as children and no `Arithmatic expressions` if you select `Expressions` and change the indentation policy to `Indent on column` I believe it will do what you are hoping for.

Btw I'm using

- Version: Helios Service Release 2
- Build id: 20110218-0911